# Polymer Behaviors sharing properties

Tags: javascript, polymer

I started to use polymer (V1.0) in a spare time project and observed a maybe buggy behavior.

I have the following structure

```
     <section data-route="editor">
        <paper-material elevation="1">
          <editor-frame title="Person Editor">
            <editor-content-person/>
          </editor-frame>
        </paper-material>
        <paper-material elevation="1">
          <editor-frame title="Address Editor">
            <editor-content-address/>
          </editor-frame>
        </paper-material>
      </section>
```

The `editor-frame` component has a title and a save button, while the `editor-content-xxx`components offer the data. As the update behavior of the content components is identical I put it into a behavior-mixin, which looks like this:

```
    <script>
       EditorContentBehavior = {

       properties: {
         model : {
           type: Object,
           value : {}
         }
       },

       handleChange : function(e){
          this.model[e.target.name] = e.target.value;  // seems to be NOT isolated
          this.fire('changed-model', {model : this.model});
       }
    };
    </script>
```

The content component looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="editor-content-behaviour.html">

<dom-module id="editor-content-person">
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }

        .width-50 {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 49%
        }
    </style>

    <template>
        <paper-input class="width-50" name="firstName" label="First Name" on-change="handleChange"></paper-input>
        <paper-input class="width-50" name="lastName" label="Last Name" on-change="handleChange"></paper-input>
    </template>

    <script>
        (function () {
            "use strict";
            Polymer({
                is: 'editor-content-person',
                behaviors : [EditorContentBehavior]
            });
        })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I expected that the properties would be isolated, but when I edit the content in the "Person Editor" and also another "Address Editor" the data will be "merged" on `handleChange`, resulting in something like:

```
{"firstName":"bla","city":"city","lastName":"glu" }
```

PS: I know a similar behavior from ReactJS, when data is not kept inside the component's state.

Thanks already in advance (Eric?!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting the default value in a function.

```
properties: {
     model : {
       type: Object,
       value : function() {
                   return {};
               }
     }
}
```

The way you are doing it currently will create the property on the prototype and it will be shared across instances. Also have a look at the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#configure-values). It could be more explicit, but it indicates the behaviour that you have described.

Comment: Thanks, Maria. This is the solution.